# Find highest depth when given a file path

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, filepath

Let's say I have a file tree that looks like the below image.
[image]

I have a function that passes through a file path inputted by the user. I want the function to find the highest depth within that path. For example in the image above, the highest depth of the folder 'test' is 3 since it contains folder1 which contains folder11 which contains fileD.txt.

My code:

```
def depth(path, depth_count=0):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        try:
            newItem = os.path.join(path, item)
            print(newItem)
            if isdir(newItem):
                depth_count += 1
            print('Depth is currently: ' + str(depth_count))
            depth(newItem, depth_count)
        except:
            pass
    return 'Highest depth is ' + str(depth_count)
```

I input this into the shell:

```
depth('C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\test')
```

The result is this:

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\fileA.txt
Depth is currently: 0
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder1
Depth is currently: 1
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder1\fileB.txt
Depth is currently: 1
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder1\fileC.txt
Depth is currently: 1
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder1\folder11
Depth is currently: 2
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder1\folder11\fileD.txt
Depth is currently: 2
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder2
Depth is currently: 2
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder2\fileD.txt
Depth is currently: 2
C:\Users\John\Documents\test\folder2\fileE.txt
Depth is currently: 2
'Highest depth is 2'
```

The issue is that the highest depth should be three not two. Also, this function needs to use recursion and not use os.walk.

Comment: Well, you could just split the root path and count the number of sections.

Comment: You add depth every time you see a directory. You should instead add depth only when entering a directory via depth(newItem, depth_count+1). However, you still have to return that, and compare that "highest depth" against all the other paths.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Okay so I changed it to depth(newItem, depth_count+1) and now I'm not sure where to compare it at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a "depth first search"

```
def get_depth(path, depth=0):
    if not os.path.isdir(path): return depth
    maxdepth = depth
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, entry)
        maxdepth = max(maxdepth, get_depth(fullpath, depth + 1))
    return maxdepth
```

which is the general approach to your solution but I think that you forgot to count that regular files have depth one greater than the directory that they are in.

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable error when running this.

Comment: Oh woops, I had the name of the depth variable set to the same thing as the depth function. I fixed it now and renamed the function to `get_depth`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def get_depth(path='.', depth=0):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if dirs or files:
            depth += 1
        if dirs:
            return max(get_depth(os.path.join(root, d), depth) for d in dirs)
    # Will return 0 for an empty directory
    return depth
```

Comment: When running that I get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I ran it again and it's working however it's returning 2 as the highest depth but for that example it should be depth of 3 not 2.

Comment: @sam44 Just noticed that and fixed it.